# Cannot Deploy SharePoint Solutions Anymore

Tags: 2013, deployment, claims-based-auth, visual-studio-2013

I have been working on this project for several months, and all of the sudden I cannot deploy the solution anymore.  I am getting this error:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool':  cannot 
connect to site https://blah.blah.blah. Make sure that this is a valid URL 
and the SharePoint site is running and so on...
```

I have done everything I have read to get this to work.  Checked permissions, checked SQL access, reset IIS, recycled the App Pools, Check Central Admin and Site Collection Permissions, I run VS as an Admin, I mean everything; well obviouxly not everything or this would work right now.

I am working on a Claims based solution.  I am not sure if this has something to do with it, or if it changed me somewhere on the farm.  I can get to the farm through the URL and it is running just fine.

Edit:  After checking the ULS logs, I am getting a Claims provider error on the custom solution's assembly, and I am also getting a security token request error.  I am not sure what I did to get it to throw these errors, but for some reason SharePoint is rejecting my assembly for my solution.

Edit 2:  Instead of carrying on in the comments, I will post here.  I was able to deploy via powershell.  When trying to access my WebApp I am getting Acces Denied which is expected right now, and another post in the near future.  I am still puzzled as to why VS stopped deploying my solution and how my solution stripped my ability to launch from VS.  Thanks for the help and suggestions!

Comment: are you deploying via powershell or directly from VS? what is your web application authentication confiuration? check the Event log and ULS log for more clue.

Comment: I am deploying via VS and this is a Farm level solution.  I have been working between two WebApps.  One is a simple Windows Authentication, the other is a Claims-Based WebApp where I have my custom Claims provider attached to it.

Comment: try to add the user in the Policy of web application with full control, the user which is running Visual Studio. http://www.stuartroberts.net/index.php/2011/07/16/deploy-solution-claims-based-authentication-site/

Comment: I did already.  I also run as an admin in VS.  I also made my account a server administrator as well, which is not a great idea but needed to try something,  still no dice.

Comment: have you tried to deploy it using the powershell, i am thinking due to your custom cliam providers it is not recognizing the ur account...did you check the ULS logs and event logs?

Comment: I did.  I am getting security errors.  It seems my custom provider, that is not working right now, has replaced SharePoints STS token issuer.  Thi sis kind of a good thing because it means I am close to getting my custom STS working, but not at the cost of blowing up my farm.  I made an edit to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my issue was that my super user and super reader accounts needed to be reset.  Once I removed and the re-added those accounts, everything started working as normal.